# Why should I embed a scripting language?

Tags: c++, python, lua

I am learning C++ now and I have heard a lot about embedded scripting languages. I imagined it completely different.

I thought I would write all of my performance heavy functions in C++ and call them out of a scripting language such as Lua or Python.

But it seems it is the other way around. -> Write functions in Lua/Python and call them in C code.

**What is the advantage of embedding a language in C++ instead of writing an API in C++ and calling those functions in another language?**

Example:

```c++
// function in c++
int expensiveFunction(){
  return 1;
}
```

Then in Python I would call this function and I would have the performance from C++ but can make changes at runtime thanks to Python's runtime interpreter.

Comment: Another reason is that you can let users write their own scripts to extend the program. This is what Unix does.

Comment: In what context are you talking about? In video games, the engine is "closed" in C++ but often things are controlled through scripting languages to allow modifications. Same for something like a server, or any software where you would want to keep the core closed but allow user-created extensions. But the inverse would be true in, say, scientific software where something like Python is simple to write but slow so core functions should be in C/Fortran.

Comment: @tpg2114: that is exactly what I am talking about. When should I consider to embed a language in c++ instead of writing the core in c++ and use it in python/lua? Maybe you can give me some advantages / disadvantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, a lot of game engines like to build interfaces to the engine by embedding Lua or Python. There are advantages to this:

- Non-programmers can interface with the engine.
- You do not need to recompile for minor script changes.
- Errors in the script might not crash the entire system.

C++ is quite useful as a backend for projects that want the flexability of scripting languages, but want the performance of C++. I have not heard of projects that use C++ as a frontend, with a scripting language as the backend.

**API Style**

We use this style in my company's software. We expose an API through a Windows DLL that can be called by most languages fairly easily. We specifically support VB and VBA. This is great when the backend is from outside the script maker's control. However, it is hard to debug issues that arise from the script maker's perspective.

Advantages

- Strong decoupling
- Accessible from different languages

Disadvantages

- Hard to debug 2 processes

**Embedded Style**

The software actually embeds the script interpreter into the software. This way you can expose features as if they were native functions. In this style, the script makers and the backend programmers typically are in the same company. It can also be used by traditional software to allow others to extend the functionality of the application. If they share source code, you can debug problems arising from scripts in a much easier manner. The application also takes care of when and how to launch your scripts. However, in order to support additional languages, the application developer has to embed other interpreters.

Advantages

- Stronger coupling
- Easier to debug one process

Disadvantages

- Only accessible through the approved language

Comment: I think most python libraries are written in c++.

Comment: That is what I am saying. C++ shines as a backend to other languages. It sounded like he was curious about C++ using scripts as a backend.

Comment: I am sorry I misread your answer. Because I want to write a simple graphics engine in c++ and build a framework (in a "scriping language") on top of the engine. So others could program something in python/lua but still get the performance of c++. I was just confused because I saw code that was embedded in c++.

Comment: I edited my answer hoping to state more clearly my meaning. As for a graphical framework with a scripting language interface, that sounds exactly the kind of situation to which this pattern applies. For scripting languages, I would suggest Lua. There are umpteen tutorials on how to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Really, either approach works fine. The question is which approach is more appropriate for your particular application.

For instance, writing performance-heavy code as an extension of a language works well for applications where you want it to feel like someone is using a smaller library in the scripted language. If you wanted to provide a performant API for graphics rendering that you include inside of a Python application, this is the way to go.

On the other hand, if you have an engine that is almost entirely written in C++ - like a game engine - and you want to provide a simple way to hook into the game engine *without requiring a recompilation*, you can embed the interpreter. This is why geme engines often write e.g. AI or behavioral hooks in a scripting language: change, for instance, the "response time" of a bot and you can see the difference *instantly, sometimes even without having to restart the game*.

It all depends on the intent as to which side is "bigger", but you can do both approaches with either Lua or Python, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I once embedded Python in a robot controller. The controller managed a robot that handled computer-chip wafers, and it also controlled various other devices. The customer could write a Python  program that did things like keep up with where the wafers were, open doors, turn on and off lights, read switches, etc.. Or it could read instructions from a serial line or ethernet and translate them into actions. Of course the fine control of the robot was handled at the C++ level, running at the most urgent priority on a realtime OS.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts are compiled at run time, while the main language would be compiled at compile time. This would make working with a large code base relatively easy as you wouldn't have to compile the entire project to update a simple script.

Comment: I added an example. I would also be able to make changes at runtime but without adding a language into c++.

Comment: @MaikKlein I've never seen someone call C++ code from Python, it's typically the other way around, something like calling a Lua script from C++.

Comment: Yeah I just would like to know why? It seems more reasonable to me to just write an API in c++.

Comment: @Rapptz Most embedded script engines perform calls both ways, very often the C++ application calling into the script on certain events, and providing an interface where the scripts can call back into the C++ side for additional information.

Comment: @Rapptz: youtube... they moved all the computationally heavy code to c/c++.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I thought YouTube moved to Python?

Comment: @Rapptz: not sure what you wanted to say.. but please read about it if you want to reply.

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that you want to use a C++ framework which bring it's own main function (and forces you to use that as the main function of your program).

In my opinion, that's often a bad design of the framework - it's not easy to use more than one such framework in a program...

The same applies for multiple scripting languages in one program: Only one language can provide the main function. All other languages must be embedded.

Note: With threads, you can get something like "multiple main functions". Well, not really multiple main functions. But multiple event handling loops.

Answer (score 1):

Besides considerations like performance, recompilation, maintainability, another reason is code security.

Compiled language like c/c++ is *harder* (not impossible) for others to know your exact algorithm without source code, while scripts are (apparently) *easier* to know its logic because they are there to compile at runtime.